# sas proc surveymeans

Tags: sas

I have a task that requires me to input a 'custom' DF value in proc surveymeans. In order to do this, I need to have a "repweights" statement that includes the repweights variables. To get these variables I ran surveymeans that created the repweight variables. I then re-ran the program using these repweights and repweights statement. To check my work I compared the output between the two programs and found it to be slightly different. Should this be the case if I'm using the repweights the program automatically generates? Any help on this would be really appreciated.

```
prog 1: 
proc surveymeans data = original_data varmethod = JK (outweights = weights_out);
var var1;
strata var2 var3;
weight varweight; /*data contains 10 obs*/
run;

data newdata;
merge orginal_data
      weights_out (keep = repwt1- repwt10) ;
/*repwt's created from outweights statement */
run;


Prog 2:
Proc surveymeans data = newdata varmethod = JK ;
var var1;
repweights repwt1 - repwt10 / df = 20;
run;
```

Comment: @PeterFlom and OP/KSims - this question isn't really a very good fit for StackOverflow as it stands.  The question needs to include an example of the code used and preferably an example using a SAS example dataset (sashelp.class, sashelp.cars, sashelp.heart, that sort of thing) or provided example data in datalines.  Otherwise this is likely to be closed/migration refused on a quality basis.

Comment: What do you mean by slightly different? What magnitude of difference?

Comment: So my understanding is that program 1 should have the same output. By output I mean the variance, std error of the mean, confidence limits. These were slightly off, while the mean and sum of weights were the same